# Identify incorrect direction of travel of Polyline

Tags: qgis, line, direction

I was trying to work on a simple way to identify incorrect direction of travel of polyline as compared to base map. However was unsuccessful. I tried few plugins but didnt get anything to help me with it.

As per the image below the polyline on right has incorrect direction of travel
[image]

Did someone face the same issue before ? Any recommendations on how to address this ?

Comment: Software? Plugins ... is it in QGIS?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: @Taras I tried plugins in qGis

Comment: @PolyGeoI am using qGIS

Comment: What  additional data do you have? A raster basemap wont be enough

Comment: @BERA i am using the Google Hybrid basemap using the QuickMapService plugin. But have no idea on how can i use direction from the base map to match with linestring direction

Comment: In no way automatically, basemaps are just pixels and if there is an image of an arrow in the photo it does not mean nothing for a normal GIS software that does not have artificial intelligence.  You can change the direction of the linestring manually. Or use an attribute and tell that the line is one-way in opposite direction. If line is a part of a graph that is used for routing then there are some more tools to find discontinued routes.

Comment: @user30184 I undestand that. I know we cant detect it from base map and I am aware to change it manually. My  question is that is there a way to automatically identify all incorrect direction. As this is just a sample. Howver total network is more than 20,000 Kms.

Comment: I would search for some open source data with roads then use this to compare to your data. Where on earth is this?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.